# Can href follow link & THEN perform function?

Tags: javascript, href, bootstrap-modal, document-ready

I am trying to create a link that opens a new page & THEN performs a function (more specifically, opens a modal.) From everything I've tried & can find on the web, I don't even know if this is possible. If I put the function on the click action, it performs the function & never opens the href page. It works as I want it to when I open the modal on document.ready, however I can't do this because when the user navigates to this page from anywhere else in the app (except for from this link) I do not want this modal to open by default. Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this? Any suggestions are appreciated :)

Comment: you'll have to use `localStorage` or a `queryString` to perform an action after the href action

Comment: Is this within your app?  Or are you linking to some other page?

Comment: You'll have to describe your use case more, but one straightforward way to implement this is with some arbitrary hash on the URL: `/my-landing-page.html#performAction` and then on the page itself, `if (location.hash.contains('performAction')) { performAction() }`

Comment: Sorry, I guess didn't include enough info. I am looking to open up a bootstrap modal that is part of the href page HTML. I can separate it into it's own HTML if that makes a difference. Will look into localStorage & queryString to see if either of them can do it. Thanks :)